# Magento 2: Custom Admin Module: On Edit data not filled up [SOLVED]

Tags: magento2, admin, custom, edit

I'm using Magento 2 Version 2.1.0.

I have below file for form.

**{folder path}\magento2\app\code\Custom\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\custom_module_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_module_form.messages_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">custom_module_form.messages_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Message Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">custom_module_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Custom\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Messages\Edit\Buttons\Back</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Custom\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Messages\Edit\Buttons\Delete</item>
            <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">Custom\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Messages\Edit\Buttons\Reset</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Custom\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Messages\Edit\Buttons\Save</item>
            <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">Custom\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Messages\Edit\Buttons\SaveAndContinue</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="messages_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Custom\Module\Model\Messages\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">messages_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">messages_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">messages_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="custom_module/messages/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="messages_main">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="messages_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">messages_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="message_status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Custom\Module\Model\Config\Source\MessageStatus</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">message_status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I'm able to add data. But when i click on "Edit" from listing, it's not displaying filled up data.

Data will be saved in database while add.

Where we can check that fields selection/fillup applies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution after spending so many hours. It's an issue with below file code. It's strange because of previous file code I have used in another module it's working fine.

Don't know why same code is not working in this module.

Only change in `getData()` function

**{folder_path}\magento2\app\code\Custom\Module\Model\Messages\DataProvider.php**

Previous Code (Not Working)

```
namespace Customer\Module\Model\Messages;

use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\ModifierInterface;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\PoolInterface;
use Customer\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Messages\CollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;

    /**
     * @var PoolInterface
     */
    protected $pool;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $MessagesCollectionFactory
     * @param PoolInterface $pool
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $MessagesCollectionFactory,
        PoolInterface $pool,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection   = $MessagesCollectionFactory->create();
        $this->pool         = $pool;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->meta = $this->prepareMeta($this->meta);
    }

    /**
     * Prepares Meta
     *
     * @param array $meta
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $meta = parent::getMeta();

        /** @var ModifierInterface $modifier */
        foreach ($this->pool->getModifiersInstances() as $modifier) {
            $meta = $modifier->modifyMeta($meta);
        }
        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        /** @var ModifierInterface $modifier */
        foreach ($this->pool->getModifiersInstances() as $modifier) {
            $this->data = $modifier->modifyData($this->data);
        }
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

New Code (Working FINE)

```
namespace Custom\Module\Model\Messages;

use Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Messages\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;

/**
 * Class DataProvider
 */
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var \Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Messages\Collection
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    protected $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $pageCollectionFactory
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $pageCollectionFactory,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $pageCollectionFactory->create();
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->meta = $this->prepareMeta($this->meta);
    }

    /**
     * Prepares Meta
     *
     * @param array $meta
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareMeta(array $meta)
    {
        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        /** @var $page \Custom\Module\Model\Messages */
        foreach ($items as $page) {
            $this->loadedData[$page->getId()] = $page->getData();
        }

        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('module_messages');
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $page = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $page->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$page->getId()] = $page->getData();
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('module_messages');
        }

        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

Can anybody guide me the exact difference between code on the point of view of Magento. Because as mentioned old/previous code works fine in another module for Edit. Strange??